# Difference between "exercise" and "workout"

Tags: meaning, differences

We can say: I will do exercise today or I will do workout today.

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: a "workout" is a "thing" -- like a "Session", say.  "exercise" is just exercise.  compare  "education" to "lesson", for example.

Comment: “Workout,” when written as a verb is always two words, “work out.”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following phrase used in the question, sounds stilted and is grammatically incorrect.

> I will do workout today. (NO)

A more natural way of saying this would be:

> - Today, I'm going to work out (in the gym)
>   or
> - I'm working out today

The polysemous phrasal verb (or *multi-verb*)  “work out“ is spelled as two words, LDOCE defines it “ **7.** <sub>EXERCISE</sub> [to make your body fit and strong by doing exercises](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/work-out)”

The OP's example sentence with *exercise* although grammatical,

> - I will do exercise today

is less common than the following structures:

> - Today, I'm going to do some exercise ([Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Today%2C%20I%27m%20going%20to%20do%20some%20exercise&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=Today%2C%20I%27m%20going%20to%20do%20some%20exercise&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%20%22I%27m%20going%20to%20do%20some%20exercise%22))
>   or
> - I'm doing some exercise today ([Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=I%27m+%22doing+some+exercise%22&sca_esv=562332091&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&sxsrf=AB5stBhmdEUnUJllG_2eYKqoSHrt2yjVlw%3A1693743636643&ei=FHr0ZJDwJrGWxc8P09Sy0AY&ved=0ahUKEwiQyrXeto6BAxUxS_EDHVOqDGoQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=I%27m+%22doing+some+exercise%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGUknbSAiZG9pbmcgc29tZSBleGVyY2lzZSIyBhAAGAgYHjIIEAAYigUYhgMyCBAAGIoFGIYDMggQABiKBRiGA0j4G1DrCViwFHABeACQAQCYAdQBoAHwBaoBBTUuMS4xuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIHECMYsAMYJ8ICCxAAGIoFGIYDGLADwgIEECMYJ8ICBxAjGLACGCfCAgoQIRigARjDBBgK4gMEGAEgQYgGAZAGBg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp))

As mplungjan and Josh61 have both pointed out, ***workouts*** are usually performed in a gym whereas an ***exercise*** can be performed anywhere.

For example, walking is considered a good form of exercise. It is never a workout. So an *exercise* can be anything: sit-ups, press-ups, going for a jog etc. Any physical sport  is considered a type of *exercise*.

A *workout* is often a routine performed in the gym, the gym-goer will exercise several different muscles in one intense session.

---

<sup>LDOCE *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*</sup>

Comment: "I am going to do exercise today" is grammatically correct.

Comment: @MattЭллен yes of course, but the OP has written "I will do exercise today" which is stilted.

Comment: But not grammatically incorrect, which is what you have stated.

Comment: @MattЭллен It's not what the OP wanted to say. The "I will" in the phrase expresses volition, personal desire, which is fine if you're having an argument with someone who is prohibiting your exercising and you then insist: "I *will* do exercise today". This is not what the OP wanted to express. But I'll edit my piece.

Comment: More natural, sure. I think that's why I misquoted in my original comment. "I will do exercise today" is grammatically correct. "You do exercise" is grammatically correct.

Comment: I'm adding a space to the verb to get "work out". It might be worth going over the orthography more in depth.

Comment: @Laurel thanks for the edit and the tip!

Comment: People just say: I'm going to exercise today.

Comment: @Lambie yes, that's another way. You should write up an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Just add it to yours. It's not worth repeating the other ways to say it which are also valid.

Comment: @Lambie  I'll just leave the comment for future visitors. If I could edit without bumping it to the main page I might but it was edited yesterday after a hiatus of nine years. I don't think the community could stand the excitement. ;P

Answer (score 7):

The have a similar meaning. *Exercise* is a more general term for physical activity while *workout* refers more to a specific set of physical exercises, generally in a gym, which follow a precise pattern.

Workout:

> - A session of exercise or practice to improve fitness, as for athletic competition.
> - the activity of exerting your muscles in various ways to keep fit.

- 10 [Workouts](http://www.everylastrep.com/fitness/10-crossfit-workouts-you-can-do-in-your-big-box-gym#) You Can Do in Your Big-Box Gym.

Exercise:

> - Activity that requires physical or mental exertion, especially when performed to develop or maintain fitness:
>
>   - "the doctor recommended regular exercise"; "he did some exercising"; "the physical exertion required by his work kept him fit"

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exercise
Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/workout

Answer (score 2):

If you work up a sweat in a gym, I would use workout. It exercises your core and other body parts and helps your general stamina and perhaps makes you lose weight

Anyone can exercise to practice something or to strengthen a limb without becoming sweaty.

I am exercising my right arm to help my RSI for example.

I can also do some mental arithmetic (exercises) to exercise my brain.

Answer (score 1):

workout is a broader term than exercise as it does mean a session of exercise.Where as exercise is not bond to be a session of exercise like in the 
gym.

Answer (score -1):

**They have the same meaning but vary according to the usage of words.**

*exercise* - training session (that is practice) and physical effort to gain strength.
*workout* - training session (that is practice) and physical effort that we used to perform action or something.

Comment: Where's the variation? When is one more appropriate than another?